# Different php coding styles

Tags: php, html, coding-style

I was wondering here, why do so many people write their code as

```
//html
<?php
     //php code
?>
//html
<?php
     //php
?>
//html
```

does this have some sort of advantage over?

```
<?php
    echo 'html code';
?>
```

Comment: Neither of those are actually good practice - you should use a [templating engine](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) and have your PHP/HTML completely separate.

Comment: As mentioned, templating is better, but if you weren't templating, why on earth would you want to put HTML into a php string if you didn't have to? The advantage is not having to read HTML encapsulated within php strings. Surely code readability is important to you? Ultimately, a web page is a HTML document with bits of PHP in it, not a PHP page with bits of HTML in it. So you should always be minimising your use of html within php tags. In fact it would probably be better if you _never_ put HTML inside of PHP tags at all; only use PHP to run your logic and output variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those approaches are poor for anyone that's not a beginner, or anything outside of a very small standalone script. Beyond a small-sized website or application, a templating engine is normally used to inject PHP data into HTML templates. The syntax of these templates differs by vendor, but typically follows something along the lines of:

```
<p>Hello {{ name }}</p>
```

The templating engine is then responsible for loading the HTML, injecting the relevant data from some type of PHP model, and then printing the result, which would of course look something like:

```
<p>Hello Marty</p>
```

There are plenty of different engines to chose from, some of which include:

- [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)
- [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)
- [RainTPL](http://www.raintpl.com/)